# How to get the swf name using javascript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have embedded a single swf **three** times named as video.swf.

The swfs names are **video1** , **video2** and **video3**.

**If I play a swf, I wants to get the currently playing swf's name?**

Is it possible ?

I'm using javascript for communication.

Comment: Your question is a tiny bit vague: first you state that it's about communication between SWFs, but then you state that you want to get currently playing SWFs name. Can you please clarify? Also, what kind of name are you referring to? SWF file name? Cheers.

Comment: Not really, but I'll give you a big fat answer, and we can dance from there.

Comment: @Benny Geo Are you able to get me now?*

Comment: wts that? you can say...

Comment: @Taurayi : hi... What you mean?

Comment: @amn : Say the fact.... we can start dance. come on.

Comment: @Benny Geo its not important, just a small correction so others can understand what you meant.

Comment: @amn: U said something... wt happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something very similar for [work](http://disturbmedia.com/) on a project for [Swatch/MTV](http://www.talkatplayground.com/?locale=gb) (having multiple embedded players on a page and playing only one clip at a time (playing a different clip, would pause others, etc.)
e.g.

```
var vids = ['video/file/72066f40bfcaea46e10460585b4e4bcb.mp4','video/file/3d5db6b87f9cdacb016c9c55afed1e08.mp4','video/file/c18b04a1a548cbf20609de70a106d7cc.mp4','video/file/4568a11f3f6a7ff467a85fefe2ac08e6.mp4','video/file/b91081d37a81692194c0e34580958c51.mp4'];         for(var i = 0 ; i < vids.length; i++){
                var flashvars = {};
                flashvars.video_url = 'http://www.swatchmtvplayground.com/'+vids[i];
                flashvars.video_id = i;
                flashvars.locale = "gb";
                flashvars.skin = 'upperBackground:0xf8c3c4,lowerBackground:0xe2e2e2,generalControls:0x000000,slider:0xb58f8f,progress:0xe2e2e2';
                var params = {};
                var attributes = {};
                attributes.id = "mediaplayer"+i;
                so = swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.swatchmtvplayground.com/flash/mediaplayer/mediaplayer.swf", "mediaplayer"+i, "578", "345", "10.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
            }
            function pauseAllPlayers(exceptThisOne){
                for(var i = 0 ; i < vids.length ; i++) if(exceptThisOne != "mediaplayer"+i) document.getElementById("mediaplayer"+i).pause();
            }
```

to get the id I've used a neat little trick I didn't previously know about (executing JS created with actionscript) using Zeh Fernando's excellent guide: [Getting the SWF’s HTML object/embed id from within the Flash movie itself](http://zehfernando.com/2011/getting-the-swfs-html-objectembed-id-from-within-the-flash-movie-itself/)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same swf file three times you'd have to pass in a flash var to let the swf know which instance it is (video1, video2, or video3). Then when a video.swf instance starts playing use AS3's ExternalInterface to call JavaScript and mark that swf instance as the one currently playing.

Using SWFObject to embed the swfs in the page you can set the flashvars in JavaScript like this:

```
var flashvars1 = {
    name: "video1",
};

swfobject.embedSWF("video1.swf", "flashContent1", "640", "480", "10.0.0", false, flashvars1, {}, {});

var flashvars2 = {
    name: "video2",
};

swfobject.embedSWF("video2.swf", "flashContent2", "640", "480", "10.0.0", false, flashvars2, {}, {});

var flashvars3 = {
    name: "video3",
};

swfobject.embedSWF("video3.swf", "flashContent3", "640", "480", "10.0.0", false, flashvars3, {}, {});
```

Within each swf you'll now have a 'name' var that can be accessed through LoaderInfo:

```
var name:String = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.name;
```

And you call ExternalInterface from Flash like so:

```
ExternalInterface.call( "videoPlaying", name );
```

This would call a JavaScript function called 'videoPlaying' with the name as the argument:

```
function videoPlaying(name) {
    // do something with the name arg
}
```